# Select Query Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am selecting records from a table as -

**Query 1:**

```
Declare @tId varchar(50); 

Select top(1) @tId = TransId 
From Table1
Where FName = 'Vincent' And LName = 'Hall'
And CustId = 1
Order By TimeStamp Desc
```

**Query 2:**

```
If @tId IS NULL
Select top(1) @tId  = TransId 
From Table1
Where FName = 'Vincent' And LName = 'Hall'    
Order By TimeStamp Desc
```

I want to get the Transaction ID from table based on `FName`, `LName` and `CustId` in Query 1. If Transaction Id is not found then run the Query 2.

Is there any better way to achieve this.

Comment: @taybriz . . . Repeating the conditional logic in two separate queries can be problematic in terms of maintenance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not necessarily faster, you can combine the two queries into one:

```
Select top (1) @tId = TransId
From Table1
Where FName = 'Vincent' And LName = 'Hall'
Order By (case when CustId = 1 then 1 else 2 end),
         TimeStamp Desc;
```

You can speed this query by using an index on `table1(FName, LName)`.  If there are just a handful of rows matching each `FName`/`LName` combination, then this should be quite fast.